# How to Avoid Retrieving IM Messages through the Office365 REST API

Tags: office365, office365api

I'm running into an issue where I'm unexpectedly retrieving IM messages through the Office365 Outlook Mail REST API. Per the docs, this shouldn't be happening (as the API as documented is only for email). Was wondering if there was any filtering that can be done to avoid these cases. From the looks of the message docs, the email looks exactly the same as another email retrieved from outlook besides the fact that the folder name is null.

Is folder name null a safe heuristic to filter on here?

We're getting notified of these message based on a `#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription` to the `/messages` endpoint. We are specifically filtering on `IsDraft eq false`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you set additional filter based on the "Message class" value?
"Standard" message has "IPM.Note" message class.